# How to obtain value of HTML <input type="image"> in the Servlet

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have this code in my jsp

```
<div class="controls">
    <input type="image" class="sprite submit-button button" name="SubmitChangeCreds" value="ChangeUIDSubmit" src="../images/layout/transparent.png" />
</div>
```

In my servlet I am trying to get the value of this image like this

```
request.getParameter("SubmitChangeCreds")
```

But this is null.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry the jsp code didnt get added in the question ... here it is <div class="controls">
          <input type="image" class="sprite submit-button button" name="SubmitChangeCreds" value="ChangeUIDSubmit" src="../images/layout/transparent.png" />
         </div>

Comment: You should edit your answer and add the code there + format it and not paste it as comment.

Comment: Read the faq for formatting rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the HTML specification, the `input type="image"` is to be used as an image map. The webbrowser will send the x and y position of the mouse pointer to the server when the enduser clicks on the image map. The submitted value is available as `originalname.x` and `originalname.y`.

So in your case:

```
String x = request.getParameter("SubmitChangeCreds.x");
String y = request.getParameter("SubmitChangeCreds.y");
```

---

However, you seem after all to be abusing the `input type="image"` since you don't seem to be interested in the mouse position. I'd suggest to just use `input type="submit"` wherein the image is specified as a CSS background image.

E.g.

```
<input type="submit" class="sprite submit-button button" name="SubmitChangeCreds" value="ChangeUIDSubmit" />
```

with e.g.

```
.submit-button {
    background-image: url('../images/layout/transparent.png');
}
```

That's a more correct usage of background images in buttons.

Comment: As per [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20101019/number-state.html#image-button-state): "The input element represents either an image from which a user can select a coordinate and submit the form, or alternatively a button from which the user can submit the form." So no abuse here, image button can be used as submit button.
Another thing from the spec is: "The element's value attribute must be omitted." And that's probably the reason why parameter is `null`.